# React Hook access in an onclick function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to refresh a component using a button and a HTTP fetch request, so I've a hook that calls the function but I need to fire it from an onClick handler in a button:

```
const {useEffect, useState, useRef} = React;

const useRefreshArtifacts = (setArtifactsStore) => {
  const refresh = () => {
    console.log("do some stuff with state");
    const [match, setMatch] = useState({});
  };
  return {refresh};
};

function ArtifactApp(props) {
  const {refresh} = useRefreshArtifacts("");
  return (<div><button onClick={refresh}>Hello</button></div>);
}

const AppContainer = () => {

  return (<div><ArtifactApp /></div>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppContainer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jre2cwbf/

Which gives the usual `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component` but I can't figure out how to externalise the hook call, I've tried a useCallback but not got any close.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of `const [match, setMatch] = useState({});`? How is this going to be used? The problem is not the click event handler but the fact that you are calling `useState` inside `refresh`. Knowing what the purpose of `match` and `setMatch` is will help us come up with a proper solution.

Comment: Declare `const [match, setMatch] = useState({})` outside `refresh` funtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code in this way:

```
const {useEffect, useState, useRef} = React;

const useRefreshArtifacts = (setArtifactsStore) => {
  const [match, setMatch] = useState("Hello");
  const refresh = () => {
    console.log("do some stuff with state");
    setMatch("refresh")
  };
  return {match, refresh};
};

function ArtifactApp(props) {
  const {match, refresh} = useRefreshArtifacts("");
  return (<div><button onClick={refresh}>{match}</button></div>);
}

const AppContainer = () => {

  return (<div><ArtifactApp /></div>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppContainer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

As you can see I have:

1. move `useState` outside `refresh` function;
2. set `match` on `refresh` function;
3. returned `match` from custom hook (`useRefreshArtifacts`) to use it on component.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L0wfhzqr/5/) your fiddle modified.

Comment: Thanks Giovanni! That's insanely subtle the difference between entirely broken and working well ;)

Comment: @TomBarber yes correct, so subtle... Have a nice coding =)

Comment: I didn't want to butcher this question so I've asked another, but if you have any insight into nested hooks I'd be happy for some advice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68995909/react-nested-hooks-with-state ! ;)